# Python: Panasonic network stream not recognized using OpenCV

Tags: python, opencv, networking, stream, streaming

I am trying to read a stream from a Panasonic network camera (WV SFV481) using Python and openCV. However the stream does not seem to be recognized since `cap.isOpened()` returns `False`. Here is what I tried (The turned off lines are the different adresses I tried to capture the stream):

```
import cv2

#cap = cv2.VideoCapture('http://169.254.5.128:581/1')
#cap = cv2.VideoCapture('admin:12345@169.254.5.128:581/1')
#cap = cv2.VideoCapture('admin:12345@http://169.254.5.128:581/1')
#cap = cv2.VideoCapture('http://169.254.5.128:581/live/index.html?Language=9')
#cap = cv2.VideoCapture('admin:12345@169.254.5.128:581/live/index.html?Language=9')
#cap = cv2.VideoCapture('admin:12345@http://169.254.5.128:581/live/index.html?Language=9')

if cap.isOpened() == False:
    print("Error File Not Found")
while cap.isOpened():
    ret, frame = cap.read()
    
    if ret == True:
        cv2.imshow('frame',frame)
    
        if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF ==ord('q'):
            break
        
    else:
        break
cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Thanks in adnvance, I really appreciate any help!

Comment: I have this problem with Panasonic AW-HE40

Answer (score 0):

This is how it finally worked: `cap_1 = cv2.VideoCapture('http://169.254.5.128:581/cgi-bin/camera')`. Here you can check what extensions you need to use in the link to acces your network camera: https://www.ispyconnect.com/